# SQL to Select lowest value, group by, other field

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having a problem writing a query that gives me the other fields after finding the min value of another column. I've tried this:

```
Select WorkOrder, min(Job), Details
From Jobs
Group by WorkOrder
```

But it doesn't work.

This gives me a list of the lowest Job number by WorkOrder:

```
Select WorkOrder, min(Job)
From Jobs
Group by WorkOrder
```

I want Details of the line item with the lowest Job number. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Since `Details` is not one of the items specified in `GROUP BY`

Answer (score 0):

You may try this query

```
Select WorkOrder, min(Job), Details
From Jobs
Group by WorkOrder, Details
```

Comment: I wish it were that simple. Imagine the table I'm working on has thousands of entries. For each WorkOrder there are one or more Jobs and each Job has one Details. I need the Details for the Job that has the lowest number for each WorkOrder.

Comment: Then you'd probably need a row based key for joining the grouped result to the master table. Do you have a primary key on the table?

Answer (score 0):

you should add min() in your condition like this

```
Select * From Jobs Where Job in
(Select min_job From (Select WorkOrder ,min(Job) as min_job From Jobs
Group by WorkOrder)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use a GROUP BY clause, everything in your select statement has to either be an aggregate function (like min, max, ect) or has to be included in your GROUP BY clause. Details is not included in your GROUP BY clause, and so the statement won't compile. If you include Details in your GROUP BY clause you will get the min(job) of each combination of WorkOrder and Details, which is probably not what you want.

There are a few ways you can go about solving this problem. IMO the easiest would be to select your min(job) and Workorder, and then to join that result back into the jobs table and select details. To do this your jobs table must have a unique primary key.

```
SELECT
minWorkOrder.WorkOrder
minWorkOrder.MinJob
Jobs.Details
FROM
(Select Key, WorkOrder, min(Job) as MinJob
From Jobs
Group by Key, WorkOrder) AS minWorkOrder
INNER JOIN Jobs
ON Jobs.Key = minWorkOrder.Key
```

If your table does not have a unique key, then things get a littler trickier. In the scope of this query, it is probably a safe assumption that every combination of min(Job) and WorkOrder is unique. You can join on both of these fields and yous should get the right answer.

```
SELECT
minWorkOrder.WorkOrder
minWorkOrder.MinJob
Jobs.Details
FROM
(Select WorkOrder, min(Job) as MinJob
From Jobs
Group by WorkOrder) AS minWorkOrder
INNER JOIN Jobs
ON Jobs.Job = minWorkOrder.MinJob AND Jobs.WorkOrder = minWorkOrder.WorkOrder
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
SELECT WorkOrder, Details 
from Jobs
where Job IN (SELECt min(Job), WorkOrder from Jobs GROUP BY WorkOrder);
```

Comment: This answer assumes that no two WorkOrders can have the same Job count.

Answer (score 0):

I worked with an engineer in my department who provided this working answer:

```
Select A.WorkOrder, A.Job, A.Details 
From(Select WorkOrder, Job, Details, Row_Number() 
     over( Partition by WorkOrder Order by Job ASC) as Num
     From Jobs)A 
     where A.Num = 1
```

Comment: Just be aware that using this, you might miss rows with same values in Job for a workorder. It will work perfectly if you have unique values in job column for any particular workorder.

Answer (score 0):

```
with cte as
(
select workorder,Job, Details, rank() over (partition by workorder order by job asc) as rnk 
from
Jobs
)
select workorder,Job, Details from cte
where rnk = 1
```

Here we are ranking values in column Job in ascending order, for each workorder. Last WHERE clause rnk = 1 fetches only the Jobs with minimum value for each workorder. In case a workorder has more than 1 jobs with same value, RANK() will assign same rank to them . Hence, if a workorder has more than 1 jobs with minimum value ,this will return all of them.

Comment: Please, add some explanation.